# Can't mass edit Billing Country in list view - why?

Tags: list-view, inline-editing

I have a list view of account with the billing country as a field.
[image]

Inline editing is enabled and working, however, for the Country field it's locked.

- I tried both with no record types at all for the account object, as well as creating 1 record type, and adding that to the list view filter.

Is that by design ? - that you can't mass change country ?

Comment: I just attempted it in my sandbox. I am able to mass inline edit country by filtering only 1 record type.

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned, it does not work on my org. any idea why?

Comment: I wish I can help you but I cannot reproduce your issue in my sandboxes.